# Adding additional compiler option(s) in eclipse CDT gnu autotools project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, autotools

Created a GNU Autotools ANSI C hello world project(https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Autotools/User_Guide#Creating_an_Autotools_Project)

How do I pass additional compiler options like for ex: lpthread?

**Tried:**

Opened the project property dialog of the autotools project created before and moved to **Autotools > Configure Settings** > Then in **Configure** tree node selected **Advanced** tree node.  Here I have selected all compiler option check boxes(like **Debug(-g), Gprof support(-pg)** etc) then added **CFLAGS="-lpthread"** string in the **Additional command-line option** text box.  Refer image

[image]

After I run **Reconfigure** project, in make file I am getting **CFLAGS = "-lpthread"** other compiler options like -g, -pg were ignored. Is it a bug?

How I can pass additional compiler options along with the compiler options provided as GUI controls in autotools project property dialog?

Comment: As a preliminary matter, use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.  The former implies the latter, but also has effects on preprocessing that you *should* engage in a pthreads build.  Secondarily, if you use `-lpthread` anyway then it should be an additional link library, not a C compiler flag.

Comment: With respect to the mechanics, have you tried just putting the flag itself directly in the additional options box?  I suspect that Eclipse is using all the options specified in the overall dialog to construct its own `CFLAGS=` argument for the configuration script, so whatever you put in the box gets embedded within.

Comment: If I write my own CFLAGS then all other compiler options(checboxes) were masked and only my CFLAGS is effective.

Comment: It sounds like you may be missing my point.  I am suggesting that you try putting just the extra flags flags themselves (e.g. `-pthread`) in the text box.  If that does not work then I can't help.

Comment: Sorry I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues here:

- this definition you are trying to add is related to the linker, and I believe -lpthread should be added to LDFLAGS, not CFLAGS
- you are trying to set an environment variable, and not a compiler flag, so that should be in the "Environment variables" section of your tool
- you should take care of clobbering the variable you are trying to set, like so: `LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -lpthread"`. That will have the effect of appending to the variable, instead of simply overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I took wrong example -lpthread here. Think that I want to pass other compiler flags only NOT LDFLAGS, then whatever passed in CLFAGS will overwrite the options selected in check boxes when checked in makefile generated.